# Database Not connectable through Public IP

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

NOTE. operation system is ubuntu 14.*

I am breaking my head over my connection on my MYSQL server. I try to connect to my MYSQL server internal through my public ip. But i am unable to connect. While i am able to connect when i connect to localhost and when i connect externally.

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

I commented the bind-adress out and this should bind the addres to 0.0.0.0. I also tried to setup the bind-adres to 0.0.0.0. This also doesnt work.

My hosts file is setup up as follows:

```
    127.0.0.1 MY-IP
```

When i telnet on port 80 to my public ip there is no problem.

```
 telnet MY-IP 80
```

I get:

```
 Trying MY-IP...
 Connected to MY-IP.
 Escape character is '^]'.
```

But when i try this on port 3306 it keeps on:

```
 Trying MY-IP...
```

I also granted all the right permissions to my MYSQL users. And i am possible to connect externaly and internaly. But it is not possible for me to connect internaly with my public ip.

Also i tried to find a solution with netstat.

```
netstat -tln
```

give mes

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

EDIT: Just disabled UFW. It still doesnt work.

```
ufw status
Status: inactive
```

EDIT2: Is it possible that mysql is ignoring the /etc/hosts file?

Could somebody help me a bit further with some great ideas where the problem might be.

Comment: May be the firewall is creating the problem? open the port on the firewall: `sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp` and `sudo service ufw restart`

Comment: Honestly you don't want your MySQL port flapping in the breeze for anyone to poke at. It's not as secure as `ssh` and is often a target for drive-by attacks, even DDOS types. If you can't use a VPN or an SSH tunnel, make a very restrictive white-list of who can connect.

Comment: I dissabled ufw for now. And still get the problem when i am trying to connect through my public ip. Also i can open the port completely for mysql on the server. Because there is a seperate firewall between my server and the big bad internet. (I know it's not the most clean way to do)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the bind address to 0.0.0.0 then restart the mysqld. Also make sure there is no firewall enabled:

```
iptables -n -L
```

if there are rules, blocking port 3306, delete them, or just disable the firwall with

```
iptables -F
```

also use netstat to check if the server is listening on the external ip:

```
netstat -tupan |grep :3306
```

Comment: Ubuntu has `ufw` and any answer that ignores this is doing it the ugly, hard way.

Comment: I checked this. And also flushed my iptables. The problem somehow is not  in any of these places. I added the line of netstat to my post. "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19999/mysqld"

Comment: What happens when you `nmap YOUR-EXTERNAL-IP -p3306 -Pn` ? If it gives you "filtered", it could be firewall somewhere on your way to your external IP.